# FontAwesome icon overflows its contanier

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I'm displaying FontAwesome icons using their API, and the icons are overflowing the container. They're not positioned correctly beside other elements. Is there a way to make the icon fit its container exactly, without resorting to arbitrary padding or other hacks?

In this example, you can see the icon overflows the container's border, and the neighboring `input` overlaps the plus.

[image: plus icon overflowing border and neighboring element]

```
<script>
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { icon } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

library.add(faPlus);

const plus = icon({ prefix: 'fas', iconName: 'plus'}, {transform: {size: 32} });

</script>

<div style="border: 1px solid black; display: flex;">
  {@html plus.html}
  <input />
</div>
```

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/shore-buffet

*This snippet uses Svelte syntax, just because it was convenient for Glitch*

Comment: decrease the font or increase the width and height of it's container

Answer (score 1):

Although the FontAwesome docs demonstrate using the `size` property to adjust the icon, this is the incorrect approach. The correct approach is to add a size class to the icon:

`const plus = icon({ prefix: 'fas', iconName: 'plus'}, {classes: 'fa-2x'});`